# Xamarin Android: Set ExpandableListView.SetOnGroupExpandListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to set a listener for ExpandableList. I have searched around but found only android specific following code. How can I convert the following android code to Xamarin.

```html
ExpandableList expListView; // suppose it is initilized
expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new IOnGroupExpandListener() {
    int previousItem = -1;

                        @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
                        {
                            if (groupPosition != previousItem)
                                expandableList.collapseGroup(previousItem);
                            previousItem = groupPosition;
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the interface `ExpandableListView.IOnGroupExpandListener` on the `Activity` (or `Fragment`) or as a separate Java-based object.

#### Activity Example:

```
  public class MainActivity : Activity, ExpandableListView.IOnGroupExpandListener
  {
    ~~~
    ExpandableListView expListView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

       expListView.SetOnGroupExpandListener(this);
    }

    ~~~

    public void OnGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
    {
        // implement your onexpand code 
    }

    ~~~
  }
```

#### Separate Class:

```
public class MyExpander : Java.Lang.Object, ExpandableListView.IOnGroupExpandListener
{
    public void OnGroupExpand(int groupPosition)
    {
        // implement your onexpand code 
    }
}
```